# How do I do reference data in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible in AngularJS, while in a nested ng-repeat, to access data from a third table?

Here's an example... let's say I want to create a table which lists actors and actresses in the first row, and then the first column would list movies. In the cells where actor and movie intersect, we might display a rating for how well that actor performed in that film. However, since only a few actors may appear in each film, more often than not those intersecting cells would be blank. If we have roughly 120 actors and 600 films, then we're talking about 72,000 possible intersections, although our dataset may only actually have about 5000 entries.

I'm using three JSON files to do this; actors.json, movies.json, and ratings.json. The first two files contain lists of the actors or movies, and extended data for each; ie: year, genre, director, or age, nationality, etc. The last file; ratings.json, contains simply the ID of the movie, the name of the actor (our data doesn't contain IDs for the actors), and the rating.

Setting up my table, in the first row I ng-repeat through the actors file to display my header row, with the names and information about each actor. I skip the first cell, as it's the top of my header column.

Next, I ng-repeat through my movies data, opening a new row for each, and then within each row, I ng-repeat through my actors data again to create the ratings td's themselves.

All of this is working, but this is where I go off the rails. I cannot figure out an efficient way to grab the ratings data easily. I did figure out HOW to make it work, by basically looping through the entire ratings table, and filtering for a match, but I know that can't be the right way to do it.

Here's some sample code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td ng-repeat="movie in movies>
            <p>{{movie.name}}</p>
            <p>{{movie.year}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="actor in actors>
        <td>{{actor.name}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="movie in movies">
            <span ng-repeat="rating in ratings | filter: { id: movie.id } : true | filter: { actor: actor.name } : true">
                {{rating.rating}}
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can imagine, this method is really (REALLY) slow.

If this were php or something, I'd just grab the data from an array (ie: *$rating[$movie_id][$actor_name]*), simple as pie, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do this with AngularJS, not at all. I just want to reference the proper bit of ratings data directly.

As requested, here's a sample of ratings.json.

```
[
{
    actor: "Brad Pitt",
    id: "13",
    rating: "3"
},
{
    actor: "Jennifer Anniston",
    id: "8",
    rating: "7"
},
...
]
```

Thanks,

m.

Comment: A few things: 1) can you post the structure of your ratings file? 2) you say that Movies objects don't contain ID, but your PHP example has `[$movie_id]`and table refers to `movie.id`. Which is it? 3) Why can't you just recreate the same ratings data structure in JS and access very similarly to how you would in PHP?

Comment: 1) Absolutely. Done.
2) Sorry, my mistake. I had IDs for movies, but only names for actors.
3) The problem is that I cannot figure out how to get data from the ng-repeat and stuff it into the syntax I'd need to get the data from a javascript array. This is what you mean right?

Comment: I would suggest to avoid data manipulation in the view. If you need the data structured differently, do so in the controller or create a service for getting normalized data. You could use a library such as [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to connect all your data in one pass rather than making a pass for each row.

Comment: Am I manipulating data in the view? I mean, currently I'm nesting three ng-repeats, are repeats manipulation?

I know that the third ng-repeat is an abomination, but that's the part i'm trying to replace. I don't understand how underscore or lodash might help, unless I tossed out AngularJS altogether?

I agree that creating a service or factory might be the way to get this done, but I'm not sure how I would make my references within the nested ng-repeat, is it as simple as "myService(movie.id,actor.name)"?

Comment: Yes you are manipulating data in the view.  You should not do it this way.  This type of manipulation should happen in the controller not the view.

Comment: Nested repeats are manipulation? Okay. Suggestions on how to handle that in the controller?

Comment: How did you plan to access the rating array as it's presented here with `$rating[$movie_id][$actor_name]`? You have essentially an un-ordered array of objects, and not a hash function.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pre-process your ratings.json array into a nested hash.

```
var ratings = {};
for (var i=0; i < ratingsArray.length; i++){
  var ratingEntry = ratingsArray[i];
  var id = ratingEntry.Id, actor = ratingEntry.actor;
  rating[id] = rating[id] || {};
  rating[id][actor] = ratingEntry.rating;
}
```

Then you could just do exactly what you would expect had it been PHP:

```
<tr ng-repeat="actor in actors>
  <td>{{actor.name}}</td>
  <td ng-repeat="movie_id in movies">
    {{rating[movie_id][actor]}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks @new-dev. I'm sorry I haven't replied to this or selected it as the best answer yet, I got called over to another project and have been crushed for the last few days. I plan to try to implement this code in the next few days and will respond then. One question though, if you're still following this... do you imagine your pre-processing code existing in the controller, or in a factory (or service)? Also, is ratingsArray defined in the Controller directly from the JSON somehow? Thanks!

Comment: It's best to create a Service that both retrieves the data/file and  pre-processes the data. The controller should be left as lean as possible. `ratingsArray` is what I called the data coming from `ratings.json` - it's an array as you specified it.